# How to select DLC chacters in Warhammer Quest

Tags: warhammer-quest

Having just purchased four of the DLC characters for Warhammer Quest (via iOS in-app purchase), I cannot for the life of me work out how to create a party using them. Starting a new party doesn't appear to give any screen to select characters, when in the adventurer's guild I don't seem to be able to retire the starting characters and pick the DLC ones, and when entering a dungeon they are not marked as ready for battle.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when entering a dungeon they are not marked as ready for battle.

That's exactly it: the 'ready for battle' ones are your current active party. You can only have four active at one time so you need to tap on existing 'ready for battle' adventurers to deselect them:

[image: Wizard selected, Witch Hunter greyed out]

then you can ready your new character for battle:

[image: Witch Hunter ready for battle]

They're always in your party out of dungeons: you should be able to choose them to visit temples or look in their inventories etc. when you're in town.

Retiring: AFAIK this means reset the character back to level 1. You shouldn't ever need to do this unless you're playing on hard and your characters have suffered stat loss through death to the point they're not usable any more. If you're not playing on hard you can leave this alone!

Comment: For some reason I wasn't able to deselect the existing party members, might just have been a glitch in the app because it's working now.